# What is range of the number of individual organelles in cells

Tags: cell-biology, literature

What is the range of the number of individual organelles in a cell?

I am not a biologist but I understand that there's one nucleus and sometimes lots of mitochondria, so I am after the total number.

I understand that different types of cell will have a different number of Organelles in them, (e.g. there might be some very simple cells with 10 but there might be some with many more than that) but I am after the range with some examples. (I need references)

This is for a computational model.

Thanks very much

Comment: This varies enormously between species, between eukaryotes and prokaryotes, plants and animals _and_ within the cells of the same species. Also, what organelles are you interested in? Mitochondria? Chloroplasts? Lysosomes? Golgi? Vacuoles? Proteasomes? The list goes on... Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organelle

Comment: Yes @terdon definitely has a point. In fact, organelle concentration is very different even in different parts of a single cell. E.g. the axon terminals of neurons contain a lof ot mitochondria to provide ATP for continuous firing, while the cell soma (the main body, which can be more than 1m away) contains much fewer of them. Another case, most cells only have one nucleus. Certain cell types like skeletal and cardiac muscle or the placental trophoblasts however fuse and form multinucleated cells.

Comment: @terdon I am aware that there are many different types of organelle. I am interested in the range of the total number of organelle (from the simplest cell to the most complex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BioNumbers](http://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/) is a database that contains exactly this sort of stuff.

For example, I took this from this site:

Number of mitochondria per cell:

Yeast Cryptococcus neoformans cell: ~34

Human HELA cell: ~6000

Mouse L cell: ~1000

Comment: that is a cool site!